# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors example on Strang's book

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: Strang's example]

This is the example given in the book. However I was trying myself to find the eigenvectors and I did this:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{cases}x_1+2x_2=0 \\ 2x_1+4x_2=0 \end{cases}$$
$$x_2=t \Rightarrow x_1=-2t$$

Then the vector $\vec x=\begin{bmatrix} -2t \\ t  \end{bmatrix} = t\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}$

No I have two questions:
 - Why I found (-2,1) instead of (2,-1), what was my mistake?
 - This system of equations will always have the first equation equal to the second, when dealing with eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: An eigenvector scaled by a (non-zero) scalar is still an eigenvector. Note that Strang says *an* eigenvector. So in fact you didn't make any mistake. He just made a slightly different choice.

Comment: There are infinitely many eigenvectors. $t = 1$ will give you one out of several possibilities.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, your solution is right, you can check your vector is linearly dependent to vector in pic

Comment: Okay, thanks boys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, the vector you found is an equally good  eigenvector as the one in Strang, as any non-zero multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector (for the same eigenvalue).

For your second question, by 'the same' I assume you mean linearly dependent? (Which in this case means the second equation is a scalar multiple of the first). This will always be the case with this setup. To see this, suppose it weren't i.e. the two equations were linearly independent. This would mean the matrix $(A-\lambda I)$ would be invertible, so we can solve the system by multiplying by $(A- \lambda I)^{-1}$, which would give the unique solution as $x_1=x_2=0$. But our definition of an eigenvector excludes the zero vector, so there would be no eigenvector for $\lambda$, so that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.